# How to schedule jobs for python code in Firebase?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to make my code run once a day in firebase server. The code is using some pulling data out of HTTP libraries as beautiful soup. I could not find appropriate result after some search. Can you give me instructions how to do it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look to `function-cron` which allows you to schedule cron jobs in `Firebase`.

> Google App Engine provides a Cron service. Using this service for
>   scheduling and Google Cloud Pub/Sub for distributed messaging, you can
>   build an application to reliably schedule tasks which can trigger
>   Google Cloud Functions.
>   https://github.com/firebase/functions-cron

Answer (score 2):

You can now use Google Cloud Scheduler to trigger jobs via Google Pub/Sub - it's a fully managed service and very cheap to run. See here: https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/