# What is the best way to schedule a batch python job in Firebase?

Tags: firebase

I have the following directory structure in my firebase project.

```
.
├── /functions/
│   ├── index.js  
├── /src/
│   ├── job.py
```

I want to run job.py every midnight in my Firebase. I have created a pub/sub job to see if I can invoke job.py from scheduler. So I have the following code in index.js.

```
exports.runJob = functions.pubsub.schedule("10 0 * * *")
.timeZone('America/New_York')
.onRun((context) => {
});
```

Is there a way to run job.py in index.js so that I can leverage pub/sub scheduler? Or is there a better way to run job.py like cronjob?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to schedule jobs for python code in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851846/how-to-schedule-jobs-for-python-code-in-firebase)

Comment: I have gotten firebase scheduler to invoke the JavaScript runJob. I am hoping to launch job.py from runJob.